# Laravel 5 - Return Full Object From Model Relationship Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model that looks like:

```
class User extends Model{

    public function projects(){

        $this->hasMany('Project', 'project_id')

   }

}
```

When I use the above method by calling `$user->projects()->get()` after initializing the class, I get a collection of only info related to the project(s):

```
Object [attributes:protected] => array(
     [project_name] => 'my project',
     [project_description] => 'my other project',
     [created_at] => '11-22-2015 04:23:12'
)
```

How do I get a collection that has data for both the project(s) and the user?  I am looking for something like:

```
Object [attributes:protected] => array(
     [user_name] => 'macdadd',
     [user_type] => 4,
     [created_at] => '11-22-2015 04:23:12',
     [project] => array(
         array(
             [project_name] => 'my project',
             [project_description] => 'my other project',
             [created_at] => '11-22-2015 04:23:12'
         )
     )
)
```

Comment: Try eager loading like so : `User::with('projects')->first()` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you should be able to use eager loading:

`$user->with('projects')->get()`

see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading